# How to disable auto binding redirect for a specific dll

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, appdomain

Auto binding redirect can be disabled for a whole project by the following code:

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>false</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

Do you have any idea how I can disable auto binding redirect for a specific `dll` ?

I'm trying to move redirecting logic from clients(`*.exe | app.config & PS | CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve`) to the class library itself.

The schema below is simplified solution which I use.

```
PS\exe(client) --> adapters.dll
                     | --> adapter.V1.dll   --> third.party.V1.dll (assembly_name: third.party v1)
                     |
                     | --> adapter.V2.dll   --> third.party.V2.dll (assembly_name: third.party v2)
                     |
                     | --> adapter.V3.dll   --> third.party.V2.dll (assembly_name: third.party v3)
```

The important thing that I do not have access to `third.party.dll`. And assembly name is the same between all versions. I just changed file names of those `dlls` in order to keep them in a single folder.
I've been using `*.exe | app.config & PS | CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` redirecting logic. But I would say that it's not very convenient. I have many different clients and do not want to update `app.config` files each time. So that is why I need to move the redirecting logic from clients to `adapters.dll`. It is easy - I just need to set `AutoGenerateBindingRedirects` to `false` and write a custom resolving logic like this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    //...redirecting logic
}
```

But the point is that I do not want to disable `AutoGenerateBindingRedirects` for the whole project cause it's possible that some other assemblies might need auto resolving.

Do you have any idea how I can disable auto binding redirect for a specific `dll` ?

Comment: I'm having this same exact issue.  The best resolution I have come up with so far is to create a post build step that removes the bindings redirects from the config.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?? Facing similar issue.

Comment: @AmitKumar yes I did. DM me. later I'll post the answer here